# Spring Security with OpenAM

Tags: spring-security, saml-2.0, openam

Currently we have web app which uses spring Security for role based Authentication and Authorization.
Since we want to use SSO I see this example to integrate Spring with Openam https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/OpenSSO+Spring+Security+%28Acegi%29+Integration
so it's like

My Web app (using spring to talk to openam) <===>  IDP Proxy <====> IDP

But when I use the SAML tracer (The plugin for Firefox to track SAML requests/Responses) I don't see any SAML payloads between My web app and IDP proxy.
Is it that Spring is using SOAP request to talk to IDP proxy by picking urls from AMConfig.properties ?

I thought of using Fedlet but reading the saml response from Fedlet and integrating that with Spring Security is not feasible.
If Spring security3 doesn't use SAML2 is it a good idea to use spring framework to talk to openam ? 
Any inputs ?

Thanks in advance
Ram

Comment: What is the IDP proxy? OpenAM?

Comment: Are you being redirected to the IDP for authentication?

Comment: yes IDP proxy is another openam instance.
yes I see the request are being redirected from IDP Proxy to IDP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok folks we got our JSF2 web app working by integrating with Spring SAML extension and Spring Security along with open am.
Spring SAML extension is here - (https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-saml)

So now we are pulling all user roles from LDAP using Openam as IDP and the saml request and response is processed by spring saml extension.  The role based access within application is controlled by Spring Security.

I would like to thank
Vladimir Schaefer - Author of Spring Saml , 
Stefan - from opensaml team, 
Peter Major- from Openam @ forge rock.

Wanted to add this note to let others know that the integration can be done to JSF app or any other web app and it uses Spring security SAML extension (which uses SAML 2.0 end to end) . 
We finally have single sign on working finally.
I will put up an article on this shortly and will update this post.

I was able to add some more notes please see my articles on
generic info related to Openam concepts
http://reddymails.blogspot.com/2013/03/sso-for-java-or-net-web-based.html

Steps to integrate JSF 2 web application with Openam using Spring SAML extension and Spring Security.
http://reddymails.blogspot.com/2013/06/integrating-jsf-web-applicataion-with.html

Thanks
Ram

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you are not using the openam fedlet anymore? I hoped to integrate our working fedlet into spring-security, but this is not the way to go?

Comment: We used Spring Saml Extension for Our J2ee based web (JSF/JSP both will work ) application and integrated with Openam. We did not use Fedlet. The links above show pointers to the steps we took to integrate. Its working flawlessly from 4 years :)

Answer (score 1):

> I don't see any SAML payloads between My web app and IDP proxy

According to the page, the integration is very similar to a normal agent approach. This probably means that you app talks to OpenAM using SOAP and OpenAM talks to the IDP using SAML.

> But when I use the SAML tracer (The plugin for Firefox to track SAML
>   requests/Responses) I don't see any SAML payloads between My web app
>   and IDP proxy. Is it that Spring is using SOAP request to talk to IDP
>   proxy by picking urls from AMConfig.properties ?

If things are working correctly you should see a SAML authentication request when you are forwarded to the IDP.
What you should do is probably start plowing through the OpenAM debug logs.
Especially the Federation log.

> I thought of using Fedlet but reading the saml response from Fedlet
>   and integrating that with Spring Security is not feasible. If Spring
>   security3 doesn't use SAML2 is it a good idea to use spring framework
>   to talk to openam ? Any inputs ?

There is an spring extension that allows you to use SAML directly. 
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/extensions/saml/index.html

You could have a look at that.

Comment: I found few pdfs which talks about using spring as SP (Service Provider) which can send SAML. Its licensed under apache.
Need to read more looks very promising.

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-saml/blob/master/saml2-doc/SpringSecurity%20SAML%20-%20documentation.pdf?raw=true

And 

https://jira.springsource.org/secure/attachment/15148/SpringSecurity+SAML+-+documentation.pdf

Comment: Yes, this is the one I'm talking about in my answer. It is based on OpenSAML which I have done alot of work with, feel free to ask questions =)